# The intersection of an infinite descending chain of non-empty sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am trying to prove something by contradiction and I am stuck as described below:

From the (false) assumption, I have shown that for any $i \in \mathbf{N}$, $A_i \neq \emptyset$ and that $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq ...$ (the inclusion is not necessarily proper). Each $A_i$ is a set of functions from $\mathbf{N}$ to $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. (So I believe it's not bounded or even continuous. Edited from here: Any element in each A_i is some function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace $ with some special property associated with $i$. So each $A_i$ is already defined. )

To achieve a contradiction useful for my proof, I either want to show that this descending chain is impossible or that $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} \neq \emptyset$ because I can then proceed my argument.

The latter seemed obvious to me at first, but when trying to write down a proof, I couldn't. Do I need to use any special tool for this, e.g., AC? Or I can't just say either of the two?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What are you trying to prove? It'll be a lot easier if you wrote that.

Comment: It seems that there isn't quite enough information to work with here.  Some general advice I can give you is that if you are looking for $\cap A_n \neq 0$, then this would be achieved if each $A_n$ is compact in some topology or metric.

Answer (score 2):

The set of functions from $\Bbb{N}$ is $\{0,1\}$ is equinumerous with $\Bbb{R}$. So your problem is equivalent to the same question with sets of reals. But then it's easy to find a chain of the type you don't want: just let $A_i=(i,\infty)$.

Comment: I guess that my question is not so clear. I meant any element in each $A_i$ is some function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ with some special property associated with $i$. So each $A_i$ is already defined.

Comment: @curious: Chris’s point is that since chains with empty intersections do exist, the information that you’ve given us is insufficient to rule out the possibility that yours has empty intersection. It might, or it might not; it’s going to depend on the sets $A_i$, about which we know essentially nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that under certain assumptions, e.g. Cantor's theorem (about intersection of decreasing sets in a compact metric space), the intersection is guaranteed to be non-empty.

Since you mentioned continuity and boundedness, note that there is a natural topology on $2^\Bbb N$, and it is compact (in fact it is the Cantor space). So it might be reasonable to try and prove that your $A_i$ are closed sets there, in which case Cantor's theorem indeed assures that the intersection is non-empty.

If, on the other hand, the definition of the $A_i$ is too "wildly" then you can easily concoct a sequence whose intersection is empty. It depends on your sets (i.e., on how you define them).

Both Cantor's theorem, as well the existence of a sequence of sets whose intersection is empty, do not depend on the axiom of choice and are true without it.

Comment: Thanks for necessary conditions of the statement.